# Hide scrollbar and swipe left right with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a created a box where I want to horizontally scroll the content from left to right on mobile and I wanted to swipe using touch and hide the scrollbar, here is a working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/xzc7khk0/3/)

Should I try any JSplugin to handle this or is this something doable easily? Please suggest

```css
.spotlight_graphs {
  bottom: 30px;
  clear: both;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 360px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#cbcbcb;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:10px;
}
.spotlight_graphs > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align:left;
  width:200%;
}
.spotlight_graphs > ul > li {
  max-width: 90px;
  width: 33%;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#dec8c8;
  height:100px;
  margin:0 5px 5px 0;
  border:1px solid #333333;
}
.spotlight_graphs > ul > li > .graph_detail {
  color: #404040;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="spotlight_graphs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="graph_detail"> This is dummy title </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="graph_detail"> This is dummy title </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="graph_detail"> This is dummy title </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="graph_detail"> This is dummy title </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="graph_detail"> This is dummy title </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In mobile browsers, the scrollbar will not be displayed as in desktop browsers. a tiny line will be appeared when you swipe, which is inset to it's container, and it won't affect anything for the layout. If you want, you can use any other jquery plugins such as http://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/demo.html .

Answer (score 3):

If you are using webkit browser such as chrome and safari, you could easiy add the following code to your CSS. Demo -> https://jsfiddle.net/xzc7khk0/5/

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to get this is using only CSS and baiscly rotating the items 90deg.

you can find it explained really well here:
Here's [a link](https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/)! where you can find this solution explained really well.

Another solution is to place the div that has the scrollbar into another div that has a height less than the scrolling div and overflow hidden in order to cover the scrollbar like this:

```
.hideScroll {
  height: 129px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

I edited your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xzc7khk0/6

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS as @Stan George said.

But this css is only for mobile, because you want to disappear scrollbar in mobile, so apply css on your scrollable div.

```
.spotlight_graphs::-webkit-scrollbar{
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

it will disappear the scrollbar not scrolling.

Comment: Why downvoted? If suggestion is wrong then assist it in your way and share your ideas. This will be helpful for me and for others too.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do with css Webkit

```
html {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.spotlight_graphs::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  //remove scrollbar width 
    background: transparent;  //optional: it will make scrollbar invisible
}
```